# Cancel function that has $timeout running

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code. It checks a factory that polls a server every few minutes. It works fine, but I want to pause the "fetchDataContinously" method when a modal is opened, and resume it when the modal is closed.  In short, I need to find a way to toggle the "fetchDataContinously" on the opening and closing of modals. Please advise, or let me know if my question is not clear.

```
    angular.module('NavBar', []).controller('NavBarCtrl', function NavBarCtrl($scope,$modal,$timeout,MyPollingService) {

    var ctrl = this;
    fetchDataContinously ();

    function fetchDataContinously () {
        MyPollingService.poll().then(function(data) {


        if(data.response[0].messages[0].important_popup){
          ctrl.showImportantNotice(data.response[0].messages[0]);
          return;
        }
        $timeout(fetchDataContinously, 3000);
        });
    }
    ctrl.showNotices = function () {
        var noticesModalOptions = {
            templateUrl: "notices.html",
            controller: "NoticesCtrl",
            controllerAs: "ctrl",
            show: true,
            scope: $scope,
            resolve: {
                notices: function(NoticesFactory) {
                    return NoticesFactory.getMessages();
                }
            }
        }

      var myNoticesModal = $modal(noticesModalOptions);
      myNoticesModal.$promise.then(myNoticesModal.show);
    }

   ctrl.showImportantNotice = function (importantNotice) {
    ctrl.importantNotice = importantNotice; 
    var importantNoticeModalOptions = {
        templateUrl: "/importantNotice.html",
        controller: "ImportantNoticeCtrl",
        controllerAs: "ctrl",
        show: true,
        scope: $scope,
        onHide: function() {
            console.log("Close !");
            fetchDataContinously();
        },
        onShow: function() {
            console.log("Open !");
        }
    }

  var myImportantNoticeModal = $modal(importantNoticeModalOptions);
  myImportantNoticeModal.$promise.then(myImportantNoticeModal.show);
}
```

})

Comment: Right, so, when modal opens, cancel the timeout, then when it closes, restart it.

Comment: I think thats where I am lost. How can I cancel the $timeout from outside the fetchDataContinously function.... For example, how could I do it inside the importantNoticeModalOptions.onHide

Comment: i don't even see a $timeout being called in your code

Comment: `$timeout` returns a Promise. Keep hold of that, and when you want to cancel, call `$timeout.cancel(promise)`. This is all in [the documentation for `$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)...

Comment: @charlietfl The timeout is there now.  I will also check the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `$timeout` in  function and return it's promise

```
var timer;
function startPolling(){
   return $timeout(pollData, 3000);
}
// start it up
timer = startPolling();
```

To cancel:

```
$timeout.cancel(timer);
```

Then to start again :

```
timer = startPolling();
```